# ArUco markers for primesense caramine 1.09 in python

Tags: python-3.x, aruco, primesense

Did anyone use primesense caramine 1.09 with ArUco marker detector in python?  I had tried to run commands of aruco detector for webcamera , it is working fine. But when I tried to run this commands with primesense I am not able to detect markers. I had passed the single frame.

This is the code

```
frame = np.load("rgb_primesense.npy")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_1000)
parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict,    parameters=parameters)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #font for displaying text (below)
if np.all(ids != None):
   rvec, tvec,_ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[0], 0.05, mtx, dist) 

   aruco.drawAxis(frame, mtx, dist, rvec[0], tvec[0], 0.1) #Draw Axis
   aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners) #Draw A square around the markers
   cv2.putText(frame, "Id: " + str(ids), (0,64), font, 1, (0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

   np.save("rvec", rvec)
   np.save("tvec", tvec)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the frame the results detectMarkers give? We may find something from there.

Comment: You don't actually say what goes wrong, only that you can't detect markers. Are any errors reported by Python?  Are the objects you use loaded/created correctly?  The input image 'gray' would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Resolved the issue. Actually issue was regarding image quality. It was very poor to get 'gray' image.

Comment: You can answer your own question and check it as answer so people in here can see it is solved or they understand what was the problem. Good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the image quality. It was very poor to get

> gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).